# error:" ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘./sys/kernel/config/nvmt’: Operation not permitted" even with root access

Tags: permissions, root, ln

I am trying to setup NVMe over Fabrics using post "https://community.mellanox.com/s/article/howto-configure-nvme-over-fabrics".
I could reach step 10, but when I try to create the soft link according to step 10 as a root user, I am getting error:

> ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘./sys/kernel/config/nvmt/subsystems’: Operation not permitted

why creating soft link in /sys/kernel/config as a root user is not possible?
is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Note: For error `ln: failed to create symbolic link` and `: Operation not permitted
` itself, you might need `sudo chattr -i <file1>` first before `ln -sf <file2> <file1>` if used `chattr +i` to locked that file before.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue, I found that in my case the problem was with the OFED driver.

When trying to run the `ln -s` command, I would see in `dmesg` the error:

```
nvmet: transport type 1 not supported
```

Following [this](https://community.mellanox.com/s/question/0D51T00007gt26dSAA/what-does-nvmet-transport-type-1-not-supported-meancontext-is-trying-to-link-the-nvmesubsystemname-on-centos-8addrtrtype-is-set-to-rdma) answer, I reinstalled OFED with the option `--with-nvmf`, and that allowed setting NVMeoF properly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the initial period ('./') in the path? That would say from the current location.

Comment: No, I just run: "ln -s /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/subsystems/mysubsystem /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/ports/1/subsystems"

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and the reason turned out to be that the directory to be linked must be created BEFORE creating the link. I checked the instructions you are referring to, it seems that they have been updated.
The step you are referring to seems to be step 9 now:

```
ln -s /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/subsystems/nvme-subsystem-name /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/ports/1/subsystems/nvme-subsystem-name
```

This will only work if both `/sys/kernel/config/nvmet/subsystems/nvme-subsystem-name` and `/sys/kernel/config/nvmet/ports/1/subsystems/nvme-subsystem-name` already exist. Now, I don't see the latter folder being created anywhere, so I would try creating that folder:

```
mkdir -p /sys/kernel/config/nvmet/ports/1/subsystems/nvme-subsystem-name
```

The *-p* option enables mkdir to create all the missing directories in the given path if they are missing, so you can directly type *mkdir -p a/b/c* instead of first *mkdir a*, then *mkdir a/b*, then *mkdir a/b/c*.

Comment: I have a similar problem when using `unsquash`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/680219/why-is-unsquash-not-permitted-to-create-symlink-and-certain-files